# Python, list has repetitive parts

Tags: python, list

I want to shorten a list with repetitive elements, by telling how many times the 2 elements repeated.

```
list1 = ["New York", "California", "Illinois", "Texas", "Illinois", "Texas", "Illinois", "Texas", "Illinois", "Texas", "Illinois", "Texas", "Indiana"]

repetitives = []

for num, element in enumerate(list1):
    if element == list1[num - 2]:
        repetitives.append(element)

core_repetitives = repetitives[0:2]

string_repetitives = ",".join(repetitives)
string_core_repetitives = ",".join(core_repetitives)

repetitives_times = string_repetitives.count(string_core_repetitives)

string_list1 = ",".join(list1)

print string_list1.replace(string_repetitives, "(" + "-".join(core_repetitives) + ") " + str(repetitives_times) + " times")
```

The output is:

```
New York,California,(Illinois-Texas) 4 times,Illinois,Texas,Indiana
```

Obviously it misses 1 count.

The problem is the list "repetitives" is not getting the right part, from the line "if element == list1[num - 2]:".

By how is the right way to recognize "Illinois-Texas" repeated 5 times?

**A related question**

The above question is with known 2 elements. But what if the repetitive part is a composition of unknown number of repetitives?

For example:

```
list2 = ["New York", "California", "Illinois", "Texas", "Indiana", "Ohio", "North Carolina", "Washington", "Illinois", "Texas", "Indiana", "Ohio", "North Carolina", "Washington", "Colorado", "Michigan"]
```

How to tell ["Illinois", "Texas", "Indiana", "Ohio", "North Carolina", "Washington"] repeated 2 times here?

Comment: Does it matter where `(Illinois-Texas) 4` appears in the output string. Can it appear in any random place?

Comment: @Christian Dean, thank you. the sequence matter so it needs to be in its original position in the list.

Comment: So it needs to be at the position where the first repeated string appeared?

Comment: yes, something like "New York,California,(Illinois-Texas) 5 times,Indiana".

Comment: What if you have overlapping sequences? E.g. `A B A B C A B C`? Should the second `A B` be grouped with the first `A B` or as part of an `A B C`?

Comment: @aryamccarthy, thank you. for my first question, let's consider the repetitive part consisits of only 2 elements.

Comment: And for the second question?

Comment: for the second question, let's only consider the definition of repetition is a fix sequence occurred more than once. i.e. no overlapping.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would implement your code:

```
from collections import OrderedDict


def repeats(lst):
        return [el for el in lst if lst.count(el) > 1]

def shorten(lst):
    repeat_els = repeats(lst)
    new_lst = [el for el in lst if el not in repeat_els]

    repeats_str = '-'.join(repeat_els)
    core_repeats = '-'.join(list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(repeat_els)))

    repeat_times = repeats_str.count(core_repeats)
    first_repeat_index = lst.index(repeat_els[0])
    repeats_str = '({}) {}'.format(core_repeats, repeat_times)

    new_lst.insert(first_repeat_index, repeats_str)
    return ','.join(new_lst)
```

To give a broad overview: The code above first separates the repeated and non-repeated elements into two separate list. It then formats the repeated elements into the correct string format, adds the formatted string at the correct place in the non-repeated elements list, and the entire non-repeated elements list is then `','.join`ed together.

Here is a demo:

```
>>> list1 = ["New York", "California", "Illinois", 
...          "Texas", "Illinois", "Texas", "Illinois", 
...          "Texas", "Illinois", "Texas", "Illinois", 
...         "Texas", "Indiana"]
>>> 
>>> shorten(list1)
'New York,California,(Illinois-Texas) 5,Indiana'
>>> 
>>> list2 = ["New York", "California", "Illinois", 
...         "Texas", "Indiana", "Ohio", 
...         "North Carolina", "Washington", "Illinois", 
...         "Texas", "Indiana", "Ohio", 
...         "North Carolina", "Washington", "Colorado", 
...         "Michigan"]
>>> shorten(list2)
'New York,California,(Illinois-Texas-Indiana-Ohio-North Carolina-Washington) 2,Colorado,Michigan'
>>>
```

Comment: Why does this give Texas-Illinois instead of Illinois-Texas? And why 10, instead of 5?

Comment: @Christian Dean, thank you. but the sequence of the repetitive elements matters. And let’s consider the times of the repetitive sequence.

Comment: @aryamccarthy Your right, I misread the question. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @MarkK I've updated my answer, you can check it to see if works out for you.

Comment: @ChristianDean, thank you! when i try it with list1 = ["New York", "California", "New York", "California", "Illinois", "New York", "California"], it gives "(New York-California) 3,Illinois" but actually shall be "(New York-California) 2,Illinois, (New York-California)".

Answer (score 0):

I think of a way to manipulate the first-try, to make it look nicer...

clumsy enough and not really a technique.

Even it looks ok but actually it is wrong - it counts the (Illinois-Texas) as extra no matter where it appears (however it should ONLY consider when (Illinois-Texas) is a missed from the 1st try).

```
list1 = ["New York", "California", "Illinois", "Texas", "Illinois", "Texas", "Illinois", "Texas", "Illinois", "Texas", "Illinois", "Texas", "Indiana"]

repetitives = []

for num, element in enumerate(list1):
    if element == list1[num - 2]:
        repetitives.append(element)

core_repetitives = repetitives[0:2]

string_repetitives = ",".join(repetitives)
string_core_repetitives = ",".join(core_repetitives)

repetitives_times = string_repetitives.count(string_core_repetitives)

string_list1 = ",".join(list1)

first_try = string_list1.replace(string_repetitives, "(" + "-".join(core_repetitives) + ") " + str(repetitives_times) + " times")

extra_count = first_try.count(string_core_repetitives)

actual_times = repetitives_times + extra_count

second_try = string_list1.replace(string_repetitives, "(" + "-".join(core_repetitives) + ") " + str(actual_times) + " times")

print second_try.replace(string_core_repetitives, "").replace(",,", ",")
```

the output is:

```
New York,California,(Illinois-Texas) 5 times,Indiana
```

Answer (score -1):

This will map your terms with their occurrences in the list

```
from collections import Counter
occurrences = Counter(list1)
```

Then you can create a new map based on it

```
sublists = {}
for k, v in occurrences.iteritems():
    sublists.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
```

Comment: OP is looking not for just the quantities of terms, but of repeated *sublists*.

Comment: It's not a good idea to use `map` as a variable name. Its a reversed keyword in Python.

Comment: @Oneiros, thank you. is there a way to output like: "New York,California,(Illinois-Texas) 5 times,Indiana"

Comment: @aryamccarthy, Christian Dean, thank you please see my edits. Mark K oh so the order matters to you... I guess my solution is useless then

Comment: Not what the OP asked.